# Getting started with Latex Beamer Template editing

Tags: templates, latex, beamer

For some time now I've been wondering whether I could create a custom template for the Latex Beamer class for my own presentations and how hard it would be. The problem is I can't seem to find any introductory material on how to get started. Does someone have some introductory material on the topic?

Comment: I think it is a bit late for it, but have you seen this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX . I think there is a lot that will help you there (or that could have helped you)

Comment: Voting to "close" aka. move to tex.SE ... that's where its home is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you need is somewhere in here: [Beamer User Guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)

I'd recommend starting with a ready made template and tweaking it, rather than starting from scratch first time out...

Answer (score 2):

Not to be rude, but everything you need to know is in the beamer manual distributed
with the library.  If you poke through the directory where beamer is located, you can also
find the code for all of the included templates, that you can then modify.

As for how hard it is, it will depend on how complicated you want your template to me.  I use a rather simple custom template and it took about 2-3 hours to learn and create.